# How to get rid of mal

Tags: malware

I've been getting pop-up saying 'chromes', 'staticstatus' and one more, I have tried installing all the anti-virus but it still isn't removed completely from the device. Every half an hour it is popping up. It is reoccurring and the anti-virus give the notification saying that it is a Malware.

I do not know what to do. It seems like I got the virus or the Malware attack when I installed some new apps. Especially I doubt on the app voot and there could be a possibility that even the other App might have carried the Malware into my device.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>(click screenshots for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: There are already [a couple of questions asking about that "chromes"](/search?q="chromes"). Have you checked with them?

Comment: Sounds like it's time for a factory reset, and then only install apps from the Play Store that you need. This type of stuff usually comes from installing apps from unofficial sources or outside of the Play Store (which you shouldn't do if you don't know exactly what you are doing).

Comment: I did a factory reset and again got these malwares, I also install the antivirus however it still kept on notifying that there is a mall where every 30 minutes and then I was sick and tired of it what I did if I deleted the payment and Bank related apps. Let's see what happens next.

Comment: I actually was really frustrated and and also was really unhappy with the anti viruses I have tried more than 5 to 6 antivirus get them always keep reoccurring. I also tried to delete the files with the Malware extensions by going into the storage folde. For about 1 hour it did not notify about the Malware I thought the problem was resolved however after I switched on the Internet connection again I got a pop up from the anti-virus saying that the same Malware is present. Really sick and tired of it

Comment: @Ckraj I am also fed up with same issue , I have tried almost all the antivirus available , but no use . The same will come again in 30 mins . Now trying to root my phone and have to find the apk path . It is some were inside mnt/sdcard/.jm/staticstatus/XXX.apk . Try to delete it. Or do you get any other solution please share .

Comment: @pravprab....hi which device do you have this problem with... I tried going into the parent folder and deleting all the related files like static status. I actually went to the service centre and flashed my mobile and for one day did not face any issues however next day the same story the worst part is the data gets consumed without my knowledge De apps on the data by itself and as a result even battery is getting drained very badly I spoke to the company customer service and they were very blunt in the response.

Comment: felt very bad so I am in touch with the service centre I'll see what I can do as service centre guy has asked me to send screenshot of the issue I have sent it and keeping my fingers crossed and hoping that we would get a proper resolution, also wanted to add that there was another customer home I met at the service centre with the same issue with the same bug so we both have complaint it to the customer service Sitar by sending a email as well.

Comment: @Ckraj my phone is Swipe Elite sense . The 'staticstatus'  eats one GB in an hour . no way to get ridoff

Comment: Yes even I've got the same phone.. and lost 900 MBs in within minutes including battery getting heated up badly.. which city do you reside in.... I complain to the customer service center once again, warned them sternly. I spoke to the service center and they told me that they were informed by the  customer care of the company about 400 devices affected it seems so they're planning to get the update by Tuesday it seems.

Comment: @Ckraj I am from Kochi kerala . I didn't complain in Swipe yet. But raised an issue ticket in malwarebytes app . They checked the issue and told me will give feedback in 5 days . If swipe give us an update, let us wait for it as only one day to go . Hope for the best .